# Android app reason of large RAM usage and how to reduce

Tags: android, android-memory

When I launch and exit my app several times its `RAM` usage increases reaching over 500 mb. When I checked memory dump using `adb shell dumpsys meminfo`  I checked unknown `pss value` is cause of problem. What is reason of large pss value and how I can reduce pss value.

```
Shared  Private     Heap     Heap     Heap

                   Pss    Dirty    Dirty     Size    Alloc     Free

                ------   ------   ------   ------   ------   ------

       Native        0        0        0   534460   531827     1604
       Dalvik    51013    17868    50664    90480    82266     8214
       Cursor        0        0        0                           
       Ashmem        0        0        0                           
    Other dev    14292       52    14288                           
     .so mmap     3810     2320     1720                           
    .jar mmap        0        0        0                           
    .apk mmap     1305        0        0                           
    .ttf mmap        0        0        0                           
    .dex mmap     2960        0        0                           
   Other mmap     1738      440      236                           
      Unknown   504718      296   384284                           
        TOTAL   579836    20976   451192   624940   614093     9818
```

Comment: Application dalvik heap size does not change much native heap size is increasing with use.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found out reason of high RAM usage. When I analyzed native heap dump of app I got to know that instances of library `libharfbuzz.so` was taking up huge space and that library is used for displaying fonts, so when I checked code there were lot of instances of `TypeFace` cretaed in code at number of places. As TypeFace are allocated in native memory and it makes native heap size large thats why RAM usage was more. I removed those instances and created single `TypeFace` instance and used it in my app and RAM usage was decreased.

Comment: how to get native heap dump and analyze it??

Comment: @AnkitBansal This link http://bricolsoftconsulting.com/how-to-enable-native-heap-tracking-in-ddms/ helps me a lot.

Comment: @anuj Typeface info helped me a lot... after searching for months i finally found the answer. modified custom TextView to use global static created Typeface. now 20Mb previous 300Mb memory size.

Comment: I have face the same problem. I'm using more and large size images to develop an app, I checked Android Studio Memory, app will tack up 100MB while using/playing app. I don't know how to reduce for this one? please help me. Thanks in advance. @harshal

Comment: Removing custom font usage via library helped me reduce 50% ram usage.