# How to increase RAM usage programmatically in Android?

Tags: java, android, memory, ram

I need to increase RAM usage in Android programmatically to observe it changes in time. How can i do this?

I tried to generate a lot of custom objects, but unexpectedly RAM usage decreases after generating it... I changed objects quantity, structure etc and nothing helps me.

I watch RAM usage in Android Profiler.

Answer (score 0):

- You can load images with higher resolution with big sizes. It's guaranteed to increase RAM usage which you can inspect using [Android Profiler](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/android-profiler)
- Use Custom Font in your app via libraries, like [Calligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy/). It should result in app memory increase. The more additional Typefaces you use, the more memory it will start consuming, as stated in this closed [issue](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy/issues/260) of that library.
- As the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler#how-counted) says about how memory is counted, the *Native* memory from objects allocated from C or C++ code takes up a lot of memory. As `TypeFace` are allocated in Native memory and it makes Native heap size large, hence RAM usage gets increased a lot. Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19661724/11040422) to an inquiry on why an app takes up more memory for exploring the reason.
- Add `ByteArrayInputStream` and allocate MAX sizes. It will keep the memory as long as it's not destroyed.